# Can I trigger a screen created in KV file from Python?

Tags: python, authentication, kivy, screen, kivymd

**Hello,**

What I am actually trying to do is the following:

I want to create this login screen where if you have the correct mail (which in this case is only test@test.com) to trigger the inapp screen from the KV file and this is my actual problem.

I cannot trigger the "inapp" screen

*The reason why I don't have my screenmanager and my screens classes in the PY file is because it gets bugged and when I switch screens it overlaps*
[Here is an example of the buggy UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar5iT.png)

What am I doing wrong in my case?

This is my **PY file**:

```
class mytest(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = 'Blue'
        self.theme_cls.accent_hue = '300'

        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green" 
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "400" 
        
        self.icon = 'testphoto.png'
        self.title = "coolapp"
        

    def login_checker(self, mail, psswrd):
       
        hismail = mail
        hispass = psswrd

        print(themail)
        print(thepass)
      
        access_screen = self.root.ids.inapp

        if themail == "test@test.com":
            print("Corect")
            access_screen

        else:
            toast("Invalid E-mail")
```

And this is the **KV file**:

```
BoxLayout:

    ScreenManager:
        id: scrin_meneger
    
       
        Screen:     #LOGIN 
            name: "login"
            id: loginn
            
            FloatLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                Image:  #Login Background Image
                    source: "./pictures/whitebg.jpg"
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False

                MDTextField:    #mail-input
                    id: emadress
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
                    size_hint: 0.60, 0.06

                    hint_text: "Email: "
                    current_hint_text_size: 0.5, 1
                    current_hint_text_color: 0, 0, 0, .60
                    
                    helper_text: "No input provided"
                    helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                    

                    color_mode: 'custom'
                    line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1     
                    
                    
                    required: True                   
                    max_text_lenght: 20             
                    #min_text_lenght: 5              

                MDTextField:    #pass-input
                    id: psswd
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                    size_hint: 0.60, 0.06

                    password: True

                    hint_text: "Password: "
                    current_hint_text_color: 0, 0, 0, .60
                    
                    helper_text: "No input provided"
                    helper_text_mode: "on_error"
                    
                    color_mode: 'custom'
                    line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1    
                    
                    
                    required: True                    
                    max_text_lenght: 20             
                    #min_text_lenght: 5              


                MDFlatButton:   #Login Button
                    text: "Login"
                    text_color: 0, 0, 0, .80
                    
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .3, 'y': .2}
                    size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
                    on_release: 
                        app.login_checker(emadress.text, psswd.text)

        Screen:     #Application
            name: 'inapp'
            id: inapp

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                MDBottomNavigation:

                #Screen 1

                    MDBottomNavigationItem:
                        id: main_screen
                        name: "main_menu"
                        text: "Main Menu"
                        icon: "air-humidifier"

                        BoxLayout:
                            orientation: 'vertical'

                            MDToolbar:
                                id: toolbar
                                title: "This is my MDToooolbar"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to access the `ScreenManager` to set the `current` `Screen`, like this:

```
    if themail == "test@test.com":
        print("Corect")
        self.root.ids.scrin_meneger.current = 'inapp'

    else:
        toast("Invalid E-mail")
```

Comment: I am so dumb. Thank you very much for your answer John!